# Converting Canon 100D to WiFi

Tags: canon, wifi

I can control my Canon 100D and store images on my laptop via a USB connection.  I want to set up my camera outside and control it and see the images from inside without trailing a long cable.  I have good WiFi coverage.

Is this possible? and what is the most cost effective approach?  I have seen a WiFi enabled SD card for instance but this doesn’t let me control the camera.  Is there such a thing as USB over WiFi, or are there any Canon specific gizmos that plug directly into the USB port of the camera to enable this?

Comment: Search Google for “usb to usb wireless connection”. There are several potential options. For instance https://www.net-usb.com/usb-over-wi-fi/wireless-usb-connection/

Comment: There is a solution named CamRanger that will enable you to do that, however, it is unreasonable in pricing in regard to the used camera.

Comment: The most cost-effective approach could be to find a slightly more recent second-hand camera (the SL1 was one of the last one to not have Wifi).

Comment: @EricS [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)

Comment: @KaiMattern [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)

Comment: @xenoid [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC It isn’t an answer in that I’ve never tried the devices on OP’s camera or any other camera. I just wanted the OP to be aware that there are such things.

Comment: @EricS Anything that "wants to make the OP aware of something", as opposed to seeking to get clarification from the OP about the question, is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [DSLR Controller](http://dslrcontroller.com/guide-wifi_mr3040.php) which will provide you WiFi connectivity and control of your camera parameters. Be aware it use batter powered router so you will be limited of the battery life (from the web page)

> few hours

P.S. Your camera is not in to the list of supported devices but according to the author there is big chance it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I know of a solution called CamRanger that will enable you to do that, however, it is a bit unreasonable in pricing in regard to the used camera. The cost of the device in the current version 2 ist about $360 which is more than the camera itself.

I have seen this device once on a workshop shooting, used by one of the instructors, where it worked well.

However, for reference, their website: https://camranger.com/camranger-2/